# Can't find variable: React

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I am trying to make a simple iOS page with a button that triggers an action.
I have followed the tutorial on how to get started and this is my index code:

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Component,
  AlertIOS // Thanks Kent!
} = React;

class myProj extends Component {
 render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Welcome to React Native!
        </Text>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.button}
            onPress={this.showAlert}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Go</Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
 
  showAlert() {
    AlertIOS.alert('Awesome Alert', 'This is my first React Native alert.', [{text: 'Thanks'}] )
  }
}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
  },
  buttonText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    color: 'white',
    alignSelf: 'center'
  },
  button: {
    height: 44,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    backgroundColor: '#48BBEC',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myProj', () => myProj);
```

The problem is that when I run it from Xcode on my device I get

```
Can't find variable: React
render
main.jsbundle:1509:6
mountComponent
mountChildren
```

Any idea what might be the problem here?

Comment: try to run your project with `react-native start` or `react-native run-ios` commands

Comment: I tried and it's showing the same error message

Comment: what's your react-native version?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

In the latest version of React Native you must import React from 'react' package

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
View,
...
} from 'react-native';
```

Comment: Thank you! Just adding that is should be wherever jsx is used

Comment: @user269867 if you split your app as stackNavigator, bottomTabNavigator etc., check the navigator components.

Comment: Do I have to do this in EVERY file?

Comment: omg thank you. Yes, I think this does need to be in every file, since jsx is just sugar which underlying it has dependencies on the `React` object

Comment: Furthermore, it has to be import React from 'react', and on every file

Comment: This answer is very old, the latest version of JSX does not need an import of React

Answer (score 7):

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

Adding this within all of the files in which you have JSX should fix the problem.

If you are having trouble finding which files you need add it to (XCode error can be unclear), running `react-native run-ios` will give you a more precise location for the error.

Comment: Holy hell that finally solved that annoying error

Comment: it gets removed when i press `ctrl + shift + O` to remove other unwanted imports

Answer (score 0):

Add the constructor to before render

```
constructor(props) {
```

super(props);
}

Answer (score 0):

Adding `import React from 'react';` in all the jsx/tsx file resolved my issue